# Как подключить свой сервис (модуль), постоянно запущенный, написанный на C# к серверу Apache?

Tags: c#, apache

Как подключить свой сервис (модуль), постоянно запущенный, написанный на C# к серверу Apache?
Пример: есть связка Apache + PHP. Хочу сделать так что бы вместо PHP, как обработчика запросов, был мой сервис. Сервис на C#, постоянно работающий.
Откуда начать копать?

Comment: Ну модуль должен быть веб-сервером и слушать TCP порт, никаких проблем быть не должно. Апач умеет быть гейтом для веб-сервисов.

Comment: [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать